Error WindowManager system_server
Ultimamente y aunque la app funciona bien, me sale este error de WindowManager system_server
¿Como se quita o que significa?
WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{7ac921c u0 com.extremaduraoposiciones.tribunales/com.extremaduraoposiciones.tribunales.Estadisticas.Consulta.ActivityAulasFaltan} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6952 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6933 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:7633 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:321 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:702 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:186 android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal:1380

Se me hace raro que no tenga este aspecto. No dice la clase de error ni caused by.
